# How to plot a displacement filed of three dimensional body？Code help

Tags: plotting

Now I know a deformation of a three dimensional body.
For example there is a displacement field of a cuboid(`{{x,0,1},{y,0,1},{z,-0.1,0.1}}`):
displacement field: `u=x+z;v=y+z;w=x(x-1)+y(y-1)`

u, v and w denote displacements along x, y and Z directions

Comment: Three `DensityPlot3D` or one `VectorPlot3D`, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried，but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? How do you try?